# RESTLET - chaining a validator and filter, why does it surpasses the filter?

Tags: java, servlets, restlet, restlet-2.0

I have a restlet in which i want to chain a validator and filter one after the other in the code. The code goes something like this

```
@Override
public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot()
{
    Router router = new Router();
    Validator val = new ParameterValidator(getContext());

    Filter fil = new MYFilter(getContext());
    router.attach("/HelloWorld", HW.class);
    fil.setNext(val);
    val.setNext(router);
    val.validate("Name",true,"^[a-z0-9A-Z]+$");
    return val;
}
```

but this doesn't checks in the filter, just works on the validator and then comes out.

But if i write this same code as given below, it works fine,

```
@Override
public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot()
{
    Router router = new Router();
    Validator val = new ParameterValidator(getContext());

    Filter fil = new MYFilter(getContext());
    router.attach("/HelloWorld", fil);
    fil.setNext(val);
    val.setNext(HW.class);
    val.validate("Name",true,"^[a-z0-9A-Z]+$");
    return router;
}
```

The above code works fine but now in case i have to create a chain i'll have to create new objects of Validator and Filter with every new mapping.
Any solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to above question in RESTLET mailing list. The reason the router is surpassing the filter is because it returns val

```
return val;
```

rather than that, if one uses

```
return fil;
```

then the call will pass through the filter chain going through filter then validator..